# Obtaining SHAP summary plot for xgboost model in R

Tags: xgboost, mlr

I have an xgboost model built using mlr package. The model is of class "WrappedModel". I would like to get a SHAP summary plot for this but it turns out I can do this only if the model is of class "xgb.Booster".

Is there a way to convert the model from "WrappedModel" to "xgb.Booster" ? Or a package which can get the plot for "WrappedModel" class model directly ?

Thanks

Comment: Just extract the native `xgboost` model from the R object. As the name indicates, `mlr` just wraps the actual fitted model in the result object.

Comment: In particular, you can use the function `getLearnerModel()` for this.